# Sending Email using Access VBA

Tags: vba, email, ms-access

I am attempting to send an email out of Access. The email is not automatically sent. I have to hit send on the email pop up.

Is there something missing in my code that is preventing the email from sending.

```
Dim strTo As String
Dim strMessage As String
Dim strSubject As String

strTo = "Hazat.Bangurah@umm.edu"

strSubject = "New Lab Charge Codes"
strMessage = "Attached are the New Lab Charge Codes"

DoCmd.SendObject acSendQuery, "std qry_Master to HPM Lab Standard Compare", acFormatXLSX, strTo, , , strSubject, strMessage
```

Comment: What popup? is the popup from the email client or from MS-Access?

Comment: Looking at this: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/access.docmd.sendobject seems like you need to use `EditMessage := False` to avoid editing it first. Always read the docs first.

Comment: The Pop up is from email client Outlook where the email is created with the attachment and I have to add send.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`DoCmd.SendObject` will show a warning pop-up from outlook even if you use `EditMessage := False`. So you can apply workaround to avoid it. First save the query to you disk and add that file as attachment. This work around can be done programmatically. Try below codes to send mail without any warning pop-up but you must set ***Programmatic Access*** to `Never warn me about suspicious activity`. See this post from [***Microsoft Answer.***](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/msoffice/forum/msoffice_outlook-msoffice_custom-msoversion_other/how-can-i-change-the-programmatic-access-options/106a6f44-795e-40af-b930-916bcf60ebb4)

```
Private Sub CmdSendMail_Click()
Dim strTo As String
Dim strMessage As String
Dim strSubject As String
Dim attch As String

strTo = "Hazat.Bangurah@umm.edu"
attch = "D:\MyFile.xlsx"
strSubject = "New Lab Charge Codes"
strMessage = "Attached are the New Lab Charge Codes"

    ' Save file to disk.
    DoCmd.OutputTo acOutputQuery, "Query1", acFormatXLSX, attch, False, , , acExportQualityPrint

    Call SendEmailWithOutlook(strTo, strSubject, strMessage, attch)
End Sub
```

---

```
'======= Function to send email =======
Public Function SendEmailWithOutlook( _
    MessageTo As String, _
    Subject As String, _
    MessageBody As String, strAttachment As String)

    ' Define app variable and get Outlook using the "New" keyword
    Dim OutApp As Object
    Dim OutMail As Object  ' An Outlook Mail item
 
    ' Create a new email object
    Set OutApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
    Set OutMail = OutApp.CreateItem(olMailItem)


    ' Add the To/Subject/Body to the message and display the message
    With OutMail
        .To = MessageTo
        .Attachments.Add strAttachment
        .Subject = Subject
        .Body = MessageBody
        .Send       ' Send the message immediately
    End With

    ' Release all object variables
    Set OutApp = Nothing
    Set OutMail = Nothing

End Function
```

To set ***Programmatic Access*** you must open outlook as Administrator. Then follow the screenshot below.

[image]