# Automated email (via Outlook 365) to 2000-3000 people?

Tags: excel, email, outlook, office365

I have a requirement to send auto-emails via O365 to a list of people (excel list). These people can be more than 1000 as well sometimes.

I have tried mail merge but it is not working as its limit is 500. Maybe VBA code can be written to pick data from excel (but that also will be limited via Outlook 365?)

Any other easy ways to do this?

Comment: Check this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64628633/sending-email-using-access-vba/64629358#64629358). You need to add loop for your all data.

Comment: [Consider using different tool](https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/office-365/how-can-enterprises-send-bulk-marketing-emails-80-000-emails/m-p/239291). For 2-3k it might not be the issue, but you never know until you get blocked