# Generate email body with values from MS Access userform

Tags: vba, forms, outlook, ms-access-2010

I created a form and would like to send an email using a button capturing data from the sub-form (based on a query).

I am using this YouTube [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=s-Z0LHgipVE)  as a guide and get stuck (starting from `msg =...`.

```vb
Private Sub cmd_EmailContact_Click()

    Dim Msg As String
    
    msg = "Dear " & First name & ",<P>" & _
        Student First name & "has been successfully been loaded on the platform" & ",<P>" & _
        "Student login details on the platform are:" & ",<P>" & _
        "Username:" & Username & ",<P>" & _
        "Password:" & Password**

    Dim O As Outlook.Application
    Dim M As Outlook.MailItem
    
    Set O = New Outlook.Application
    Set M = O.CreateItem(olMailItem)
    
    With M
        .BodyFormat = olFormatHTML
        .HTMLBody = Msg
        .To = Email
        .Subject = "Student available on OARS"
        .Display        
    End With
    
    Set M = Nothing
    Set O = Nothing

End Sub
```

Variables are populated on a query on the form.
First name (Name of teacher)
Student First name
Username
Password

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Sending Email using Access VBA](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64628633/sending-email-using-access-vba)

Comment: What is `Student First name`? Are you thinking that is some sort of variable name? fwiw, I do not recommend using youtube to learn how to code.

Comment: What you are really asking is "how do i create a string on multiple lines using variables?" because the rest of the code is fine (and has nothing to do with actually sending emails from anywhere), although i don't think `.BodyFormat` is needed.

Comment: Try `msg = "Test"` instead of that block of code that sets `msg` and it should work.

Comment: Thanks for your advice BraX. I'll give the msg = "Test" a try.

I'd like to include the variables below in the body of text in the email. Variables are populated on a query on the form.
 - First name (Name of teacher)
 - Student First name
 - Username
 - Password

Comment: @braX - Msg = "Test" works! 

Can you advise how to link multiple strings over multiple lines with query results? 

Thanks

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16624550/how-to-break-long-string-to-multiple-lines/16624590

Comment: and the `<P>` in your string means "paragraph" in HTML, which translates to "new line in the email". (kinda a sloppy way to do it, but it will work) - an alternative would be to use `<br>` instead. so try this next `Msg = "Test<br>Test2<br>Test3"` and notice what that does to see what i mean.

Answer (score 1):

To send the email as HTML, you will need to format the body with HTML tags and set the `HTMLBody` property of the `olMailItem` (email) as shown below.

The example uses late binding (no reference to Outlook needed) which means it can run with different versions of outlook installed.

```
Private Sub cmd_EmailContact_Click()

    Dim firstName As String, _
        studentFirstName As String, _
        userName As String, _
        password As String, _
        email As String, _
        body_ As String
    
    'provide values
    firstName = "ABC"
    studentFirstName = "XYZ"
    userName = "User"
    password = "Pass"
    email = "foo@bar.com"
    
    'build body
    body_ = "<p> Dear" & firstName & ", </p>" _
          & "<p>" & studentFirstName & " has been successfully been loaded on the platform. </p>" _
          & "<p> Student login details on the platform are: </p>" _
          & "<p> Username: " & userName & "</p>" _
          & "<p> Password: " & password & "</p>"

    'send email
    With CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
        With .CreateItem(0) 'olMailItem
            .BodyFormat = 2 'olFormatHTML
            .To = email
            .Subject = "Student available on OARS"
            .HTMLBody = "<html><head></head><body>" & body_ & "</body></html>"
            .Display
        End With
    End With
    
End Sub
```

You will need to provide values for the following variables:

- FirstName
- StudentFirstName
- UserName
- Password
- Email